# Format Hours/Minutes in SSRS Expression

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I was trying to combine two separate date/time fields into one text box through an expression in SSRS.

My expression is:

```
=Format(Fields!EarlyShiftStart.Value,"hh:mm tt") & "-" & Format(Fields!LateShiftEnd.Value,"hh:mm tt")
```

And it looks to be correct in the report:

[image: Drive_Times]

But I am getting a warning when I preview the report:

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the
>   textrun ‘Textbox49.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input
>   string was not in a correct format

Not sure why this warning occurs, as it looks to be correct.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about it but there is seems to be the wrong input string getting from the database. My best guess is that there are 2 reasons in your case this was happening
   1) Some where in your data might present the `null` value. 
If you want to avoid the warning I will suggest to you that use the expression as,

```
 =Format(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!EarlyShiftStart.Value),"00:00",Fields!EarlyShiftStart.Value),"hh:mm tt") & "-" & Format(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!LateShiftEnd.Value),"00:00",Fields!LateShiftEnd.Value),"hh:mm tt")
```

This will filter out the incoming `NULL` values.

2) You are concatenating the two values with `-` so that could be the reason as you are formatting both your values as `Time` and then concatenating with `string` value. So try to change your expression as,

```
 =CStr(Format(Fields!EarlyShiftStart.Value,"hh:mm tt")) & "-" & CStr(Format(Fields!LateShiftEnd.Value,"hh:mm tt"))
```

This will force convert your time values to the string and then con-cat them.

I would also suggest you to look at your incoming values if all values are in the correct format. So you can make changes in your expression accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Coder. I'm using your 2nd solution as there should not be a case of a NULL in the field.  Thanks again!